# Previously Working Quickbooks Integrated Applications Crash On Fresh Server Install

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, quickbooks

We have just migrated to a new server for one of our clients and we have two applications that integrate with Quickbooks using the Quickbooks COM library. Both of these applications worked without issue on the previous server, and both still boot and run up until the point that they actually call to interface with Quickbooks (specifically the OpenConnection call), at which point they crash with the same NTDLL error (with the same offset).

One of these applications is T-Hub by Atandra, and one is a custom application our company deployed to integrate with other of our custom applications for this client.

We also have an internal server that has a working Quickbooks install with the custom application.

Additionally, the applications worked correctly initially on the new server, but began failing as soon as we installed the QB client on it. Following are the details of the fault:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: {redacted}
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    58232641
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_5648
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18233
  Fault Module Timestamp:   56bb4e1d
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: PCH_ED_FROM_ntdll+0x0003C7EC
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5648
  Additional Information 2: 564873ffcb97a7464af12b9608aaad29
  Additional Information 3: faad
  Additional Information 4: faad37a8518b385103d96b58fc6b8d7b
```

Debugging in disassembly reveals that heap corruption occurred at `0x76fa6054` in both cases.

Both servers are running Windows Server 2012 R2. The Quickbooks client in use is version 16.0. T-Hub is v10.507. DEP is enabled with no exceptions on both the old and new server.

EDIT: With as close of a replicated environment as we can get on a cloned version of our internal server, we haven't been able to reproduce the issue yet. However the issue is consistent, the current server is our second attempt where the first had the same issue.

At this point I'm not really sure what other steps I can take to diagnose this exact issue. What are some other things I can look at, or if anyone has run into this issue before what was the solution?

Comment: There are quite a lot of facts in the text and everything is explained pretty good, but what is your question?

Comment: Fixed now, forgot to do that in my "client needs this fixed last week" panic

Comment: You need to provide: The application version and release date, the previous os version, and the settings on the previous os for DEP and ASLR.

Comment: I did specify OS, but updated to include application versions and DEP settings. I don't know about ASLR. For background, I'm the developer that wrote the custom application, not actually a server admin. Our server admin is just as stumped as I am though.